# Flash message is not displayed when redirecting to route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have the following code to associate a contact to a lead:

```
public function selectSalesConsultant($uuid)
{
    $lead = Lead::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();

    return view('dealer-contacts.select_consultant')
        ->with(compact('lead'));
}

public function updateSalesConsultant(Request $request, $uuid)
{
    $lead = Lead::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();

    $lead->update([
        'contact_id' => $request->get('contact_id')
    ]);

    Flash::success('Sales Consultant information updated for the lead.');

    return to_route('select-sales-consultant', ['uuid' => $uuid]);
}
```

In my second function, after the lead is updated, I'd like to display a success message:

```
Flash::success('Sales Consultant information updated for the lead.');

return to_route('select-sales-consultant', ['uuid' => $uuid]);
```

Here is what I have in my view:

```html
@include('flash::message')
```

Here is how the route is defined inside `routes/api.php`:

```php
Route::get('/select-sales-consultant/{uuid}', [App\Http\Controllers\LeadController::class, 'selectSalesConsultant'])
    ->name('select-sales-consultant');
```

Nothing gets displayed. If, instead of redirecting, I do a `return view()`, the message does get displayed.

What's the proper way of doing this? I'm using the `Laracasts Easy flash notifications` package.

Comment: why not just move the route to routes/web.php ? the result is always redirect, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was because I was using an API route.

I added the following to my `Kernel.php`, and it resolved the issue.

```
'api' => [
   \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   //etc
],
```

Comment: why not just move the route to the `web.php` file which has the `web` stack applied?

Comment: agreed with @lagbox Flah message in api route doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @lagbox I agree, I moved it to web.

Answer (score 0):

Please check app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ...
    ],

  ....
];
```

and then try to use `quest->session()->flash()`function.

```
public function updateSalesConsultant(Request $request, $uuid)
{
    ...
    //Flash::success('Sales Consultant information updated for the lead.');
    $request->session()->flash('success', 'Sales Consultant information updated for the lead.');
    ...
}
```